# Why is Galactic Railroad mentioned in an Utena duel song?

Tags: revolutionary-girl-utena, crossovers

In episode 12 of Revolutionary Girl Utena, part of the chorus song for the Tenjou-Touga duel is:

> Oh, dance! Your dream, three of the seven wonders of the world,
>   carried here on the Galactic Railroad.

Now, I'm assuming that means [this Galactic Railroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_on_the_Galactic_Railroad). I know Utena's dialog, especially the duel chorus songs, are pretty vague and cryptic, but is there some significance/obvious meaning to the reference?

Note: Not really a cross-over, but that's the closest tag I could find for cross-anime references.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Lyrics from Utena duel songs talk about high abstract concepts which do not have a direct significance to the duel they accompany (or any other duel). In my opinion, it is just inicidental.